# Parse XML elements in C++

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml2

I'm using tinyxml2 and I want to parse some elements from XML in C++. For example

```
<root>
     <First x="1" y="2">
     <Second x = "1">
     <Second y = "2">
</root>
```

I can parse only x in "Second" element.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tinyxml2.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace tinyxml2;
using namespace std;
int main(){
     tinyxml2::XMLError eResult = xml_doc.LoadFile("test.xml");
     if (eResult != tinyxml2::XML_SUCCESS) return false;

     tinyxml2::XMLNode* root = xml_doc.FirstChildElement("root");
     if (root == nullptr) return false;

     tinyxml2::XMLElement* First = root->FirstChildElement("First");
     if (First == nullptr) return false;

     double x1 = std::stod(First->Attribute("x"));
     double y1 = std::stod(First->Attribute("y"));

     tinyxml2::XMLElement* Second = root->FirstChildElement("Second");
     if (Second == nullptr) return false;

     double x2 = std::stod(Second->Attribute("x"));
     double y2 = std::stod(Second->Attribute("y"));

     system("pause");
}
```

when I'm trying same method for "First" element or for "Second y", it just shows me errors. What should I do?

Comment: Kindly show your code.

Comment: open tinyxml2 tutorial and just use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining "double x" twice. Try

```
double first_x = std::stod(First->Attribute("x"));
double first_y = std::stod(First->Attribute("y"));
```

and

```
double second_x = std::stod(Second->Attribute("x"));
```

Your compiler should have stopped you though, always look out for warnings!

Comment: That's not a problem actually. I'm using struct right now. I've just used "First" and "Second" as an example, just so the code wouldn't be big for a question